# how to get error/validation messages in a variable either at page side or class side for field validations

Tags: apex, visualforce, errormessages, adderror

I want to customize the error msg which comes like: when i give wrong format of email id to email field so on below the fields error appear **Error**`: Invalid Email Address.`

at the same time in debug log this appears :
`VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Invalid Email Address.`
 `VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Email: Invalid Email Address.`

is there a way to get these message in some variable so i can show them in my customize UI ? as well i want to render a particular section of page based on some variable, that variable should know does it have a exception/validation message or not.

Comment: Pls check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635533/validate-email-address-textbox-using-javascript

Comment: i want email validation from sf side only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all validation messages of the current context by using this code

```
ApexPages.getMessages()
```

which return a list of `Apex.Message` Object.
You can use this in your controller to write a debug log or to customize the display of your message without using the default component

```
<apex:messages />
```

or

```
<apex:message />
```

Comment: Here problem comes, bcz for field validation, controller is not called. So we can't use `ApexPages.getMessages()`.

Comment: I thing I'm not getting you. Salesforce validate data only upon an save operation. And this Can not be done  in VF without a call to a controller action. If you only want client side validation , I thing you will have to implement it manually because I dont know a way to access salesforce validation messages without a save context.

Answer (score 0):

Put an `<apex:messages />` tag on your page. You can style it as you want.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messages.htm

Comment: I want error value in some variable, so i can do some rerendering based on that

Comment: Check this out: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_message.htm and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm

Comment: i want to render a part of html based on error message, you are not getting me.

Comment: See the second link above, you will need to find your message and store it in a controller variable, then reference it on the page accordingly.

Comment: but for field validation error, it doesn't call any method itself, so when i will call those method and store the value in variable.